# Square of dot product

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space of square integrable functions from $T$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is the following equality is true? $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}=\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}^{2},f,g\in H$, or how we could simplify $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}$? Thank you in advance,

Comment: Of course yo may write $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}=\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}^{2}$.  Or somewhat exotic $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}=\left\langle\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H} f,g\right\rangle _{H}$.

Comment: $\langle f,g\rangle_H$ is a real number so of course $\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}=\left\langle f,g\right\rangle _{H}^{2}$ is true.

Comment: This is just the equality defining what the square is.

Comment: Thank you so much to all, I know it is little thing